# How to Format User Inputs Into Variables in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to format a user input into variables. I'm a novice to most advanced functions in python, but here's an example prompt:

```
userInput = input("Enter your four-character list:")
```

The user is supposed to enter three or four characters, a mix of letters and numbers. I would like to slice up the input into variables that can be plugged into other functions. For example, if the user input is "4 5 s t," I would like each of the four characters to be a variable. Spacing also shouldn't matter, whether it's at least one or five between each.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using arrays, but I'm not good at all at advanced python functions. I've read some documentation on lists and tuples, but I'm not sure how to use them.

Comment: Read about `split()`, looks like a good fit for your problem.

Comment: I just did a split function and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to add, but how do you then divide up the split into variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the split method of strings in python

```
my_args = userInput.split()
```

This will return a python list of the input elements regardless of how many spaces there are.

Then you can work with your list like this

```
for arg in my_args:
    #do something
```